# System image/Backup & restore

Tags: backup, disk-image

I am running Windows 7 64-bit.  If I "create a system image" is that the same thing as selecting all files/folders on all HDDs and carrying out a "backup & restore" please?
If they are not the same, what is the difference[s]?

Answer (score 1):

**BackUp**

Windows Backup allows you to make copies of data files for all people that use the computer. You can let Windows choose what to back up or you can select the individual folders, libraries, and drives that you want to back up. By default, your backups are created on a regular schedule. You can change the schedule and you can manually create a backup at any time.

**System Image**

A system image is an exact copy of a drive. By default, a system image includes the drives required for Windows to run. It also includes Windows and your system settings, programs, and files.

**Restore**

System Restore helps you restore your computer's system files to an earlier point in time. It's a way to undo system changes to your computer without affecting your personal files, such as e‑mail, documents, or photos.

Comment: Thanks for that, Tiago.  So backup and image are effectively the same - both being copies that include files/folders.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between backing up files and backing up a system image is that, in addition to your valuable data, with a system image you also copy your settings and applications.

If you use a lot of different programs regularly and have customized Windows to your own needs, this is most likely the solution you want. Bear in mind, however, that come restore time, you can't restore individual files. You can only reinstate the entire drive.